# Update variable value in function

Tags: php, class, oop

I am updating a *private* attribute of a class that has a *singleton pattern* implemented and I am changing its value in one function of a class but in other function its value is not changing. Here is my class:

```
class notifications
    {
        private static $contacts = array(
            "+11112223333" => array(
                "status" => "pending"
            ),
            "+14445556666" => array(
                "status" => "pending"
            )
        );
        private $next = false;
        private $log;

        // Singleton instance
        private static $instance;

        private function __construct()
            { 
                $this->log = fopen("log.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
            }

        // getInstance method
        public static function getInstance()
            {
                if(!self::$instance) {
                  self::$instance = new self();
                }

                return self::$instance; 
            }

        // Send Notification via Call
        public function notifyCall($message)
            {
                $client = new Services_Twilio($this->account_sid, $this->auth_token);

                try {
                    $keys = array_keys(notifications::$contacts);
                    foreach ($keys as $key) {
                        fwrite($this->log, "sending notification to ".$key."\n");
                        // Sending call logic here
                        $this->next = false;
                        while(!$this->next) {
                            echo $this->next;
                            if($this->next === -1)
                                die;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    fwrite($this->log, $e->getMessage());
                    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
                }

                fclose($this->log);
                http_response_code(200);
            }

        // Set status for call
        public function setStatus($recipient, $status)
            {
                $recipient = str_replace(" ", "+", $recipient);
                $file = fopen("status.txt", "a+");
                fwrite($file, $recipient." : ".$status."\n");
                $keys = array_keys(notifications::$contacts);
                notifications::$contacts[$recipient]["status"] = $status;

                if(notifications::$contacts[$recipient]["status"] === "in-progress") {
                    fwrite($this->log, "notifying next contact");
                    $this->next = -1;
                }
                else if(notifications::$contacts[$recipient]["status"] === "busy" || notifications::$contacts[$recipient]["status"] === "no-answer") {
                    fwrite($this->log, "Next!");
                    $this->next = true;
                }

                foreach ($keys as $key) {
                    echo "$key: ".notifications::$contacts[$key]['status']."\n";
                }

                fclose($file);
            }
    }
```

Here is how i use this class

```
require_once("notifications.php");
$recipient = $_POST["To"];
$status = $_POST["CallStatus"];
$notification = notifications::getInstance();
$notification->setStatus($recipient, $status);
```

Please note that both classes and status update are on separate files and they have different URLs but the contacts and their statuses are shared among both files

What I get as output in my log file is that it started sending call to first contact and the status is received as well and recorded in `setStatus`function as well a `next` is printed in log file but on the `sendNotificationCall` function it does not actually end while loop nor it send notification to next contact.

Can anyone please guide me what I am dong wrong here? I also tried making `$next` as `static` like `$contacts` but it did not worked as well so I am confused about the mistake.

Comment: i'm inhibited to answer b/c of all the code in this question. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How are you calling it? `notifications::getInstance()->notifyCall('foobar')`?

Comment: Yeah @Robbie you are right I call it like that

Comment: @jeremy i have updated the code now